# Redirect error after updating Wordpress to 5.4.2

Tags: redirect

After updating to WP 5.4.2 I am getting this error message when I try to access the site

```
HTTP redirect status code must be a redirection code, 3xx.
```

At first I could see some pages and access the dashboard. I could change themes and I could deactivate plugins but I could not activate or reactivate them. Also I could see the regular public pages in the browser. But now I can't access anything at all. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean you can't access anything at all? What happens? Do you have access to your error log in your web hosting to see what's happening?

Comment: ALL that you see on the screen is that error message: "HTTP redirect status code must be a redirection code, 3xx."

Comment: The host redid the 5.4.2 install and it seems to have fixed the problem.